# Alternative to Qubes OS network domain for a server

Tags: network, firewalls, virtualization, qubes-os

I know that Qubes Os is not suitable for a server use, but some of its features are quite interesting for that. In fact, all the [network drivers](https://www.qubes-os.org/attachment/wiki/QubesArchitecture/arch-spec-0.3.pdf) are contained in a VM that run a different Linux based system and the connections from the "main OS" to the network are made through TCP/IP with that VM. Moreover, network drivers have been moved out from the main OS kernel. That allows to prevent the use of a potential bug in the network driver.

How can I reproduce the same configuration ? 
I thought about using Xen with a virtual network, but I would like to know if somebody already made it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a glance at the [Qubes OS source code repositories](https://github.com/QubesOS) you will be surprised to find out that most of the code is not written in C but in Python and Shell script. This is not without reason: many of its core features (PCI passthrough, virtual networks, VM templates with layering and snapshots...) were [already available in Xen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software#Other_features) and the Linux kernel, and what Qubes really does is gluing all those together to create a beautiful seamless and effortless desktop experience that would otherwise be an cumbersome to configure by hand and actually be suitable for everyday use.

However, as most servers don't really need a seamless GUI experience and [Libvirt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libvirt) does some of the heavy lifting, the task becomes much simpler and the amount of work needed is reduced to relatively tolerable levels for an experienced sysadmin (Nevertheless, I am also linking to native Xen docs for those who believe that [real programmers don't use Pascal](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/%7Eelf/hack/realmen.html) or who simply wants to know how thinks work underneath).

**Note**: Enterprise Linux distributions most likely have tools and utilities to manage virtual machines comfortably from fancy web control panels, and [Openstack](https://www.openstack.org/software/) also has it. However, the former's licenses usually are more expensive than the used 1U servers you can find online and the latter simply deploys an entire cloud on a cluster...

Before you start you will need to know about the following subjects:

- [**Drive / System Encryption**](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)
- [**Types of virtualization**](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Understanding_the_Virtualization_Spectrum)
- Domain **Configuration Files Format** ([Libvirt](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html)) ([Xen](https://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.14-testing/man/xl.cfg.5.html))
- [**Logical Volumes**](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvm.8.html), [**Thin Provisioning** and **Snapshotting**](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmthin.7.html) ([Link for repairs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351921/lvm-how-to-recover-lvm-thin-pool-volume-after-failed-repair/))
- **Virtual Networking** ([Libvirt](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/VirtualNetworking)) ([Xen](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Networking), [Format](https://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.14-testing/man/xl-network-configuration.5.html)). You will need to set up fixed private IP and gateway addresses and enable IP forwarding for [direct](https://www.libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#examplesDirect) connections between VMs or implement a Firewalled [isolated network](https://www.libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#examplesPrivate) with DHCP. On plain Xen you may find yourself having to edit the files inside `/etc/xen/scripts/` to make complex routing setups work, see [Vif-route](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Vif-route).
- **Firewalling** ([Libvirt](https://libvirt.org/firewall.html), [Format](https://www.libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html)) ([Xen](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/iptables.8.html))
- **PCI Passthrough** ([Libvirt](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_host_configuration_and_guest_installation_guide/chap-virtualization_host_configuration_and_guest_installation_guide-pci_device_config)) ([Xen](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_PCI_Passthrough))
- **USB Passthrough** ([Libvirt](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#usb-pci-scsi-devices)) ([Xen](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_USB_Passthrough))
- [**Bind mounts**](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) to set the private `/rw` logical volumes at the right mountpoints.
- [**Systemd Services**](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) to start and stop VMs in the right order at boot: Gateway VMs' network interfaces need to be up first for others to become attached to them.
- **Hooks** ([Libvirt](https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html)) to trigger snapshotting and network settings changes when VMs start and stop.
- [**Shell scripting**](https://guide.bash.academy/) / [**Configuration management**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) software to define the network config and snapshotting changes logic.
- **High Availability** (**Optional**, only for production servers)

  - Shared Storage ([SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network), [DRBD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Replicated_Block_Device), [Distributed filesystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_distributed_file_systems#FOSS))
  - Clustering ([Pacemaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacemaker_(software)), [Corosync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corosync_Cluster_Engine))
  - Live Migration ([Libvirt](https://libvirt.org/migration.html)) ([Xen](https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Migration))

Now, to set up a server system similar to Qubes, on **Dom0** one would have to install a minimal Fedora (latest kernel/packages) or CentOS (stability, make sure the kernel version isn't too old) witk LUKS system encryption, the /boot partition, a Logical Volume Manager partition with a thin provisioning pool and, at least, the root and swap logical volumes (don't make the swap thin). Once finished, install Xen and its dependencies.

When it comes to **TemplateVMs**, Qubes usually creates a *root* (`/`) and *private* (`/rw /home /usr/local`) logical volumes for each of them and creates a snapshot of both before starting the VM and mounting them. They are both readable and writable and, when the VM stops, the snapshots are removed.

**AppVMs** though, only have a *private* (`/rw /home /usr/local /var/spool/cron`) logical volume and, right before the VM starts, Qubes makes a snapshot of the TemplateVM's *root* partition (or from another snapshot in case the TemplateVM is running) and mounts the new snapshot as *root* (`/`). They are both readable and writable too. However, when the AppVM stops, the *root* snapshot is removed discarding thus all previous changes.

**DispVMs** create both a *root* and *private* snapshots of the TemplateVM and AppVM logical volumes respectively before starting, and discards both after stopping.

Answer (score 0):

> "That allows to prevent the use of a potential bug in the network
>   driver."

In the host ... 
The network VM is now the vulnerable part and certainly one of the more important VM's.

> "How can I reproduce the same configuration ? I thought about using
>   Xen with a virtual network, but I would like to know if somebody
>   already made it."

Depends on the hypervisor and OS. You are looking for something like PCI passthrough, DDA, SR-IOV

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.